# Why does the Synchronized method always return false?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In Windows Phone 8 (only on **device**!) try running this code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var myTrue = GetTrue();
    Debug.WriteLine(myTrue);
    // false
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
private static bool? GetTrue()
{
    return true;
}
```

You will see `myTrue` always is **False**! Why?! How it can be?!

**UPDATE**: Tested on devices: Nokia Lumia 920, HTC 8X, Nokia Lumia 925

Comment: How about `myTrue.Value`?

Comment: The same result. 

Result will be different, if method is not static or not Boolean? or if method not marked as MethodImplOptions.Synchronized

Comment: What happens if you change GetTrue() to `return (bool?) true;` ?

Comment: @gleng The same situation. I add that if you return null - the GetTrue().HasValue is always true. It means no matter what you return false,true,null - you always get GetTrue.HasValue = true, GetTrue().Value = false. But when you comment [MethodImpl] everything works all right.

Comment: Quacks like a jitter bug, there's been trouble before with the optimizer.  Report this at connect.microsoft.com, don't forget to mention the phone details.  A possible workaround is [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]

Comment: `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized | MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` doesn't have any effect. Still returns `false`.

Comment: It works for me. I get true.

Comment: @HansPassant wouldn't it make sense to post your comment as answer, so that this question can be removed from the unanswered list?

Comment: No, it is just a guess.  We don't even know the phone that has this problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah sorry miss-read, thought OP verified the proposed solution. Sorry

Comment: OP should say which device so somebody can reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that kind of behavior is due to this:

> **Windows Phone**
>
> Specifying the Synchronized option for the MethodImplAttribute constructor is not supported and will not result in synchronized behavior.

Check it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=vs.105%29.aspx